# What is the difference between _malloca and malloc?

Tags: c++

I was analyzing my code with Visual Studio static code analysis. I initialized my pointer using `malloc` with a size and then through a loop I tried to access it. There I got warning for C++ warning [code 6085](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/c6385?view=vs-2019).

When I changed my implementation from `malloc` to `_malloca` the error went away.

Can someone please explain me what is the difference between `malloc` and `_malloca` in C++?

Answer (score 5):

According to the reference documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/5471dc8s(v%3Dvs.140)), `_malloca` allocates memory on the stack rather than on the heap. The size of the allocated array is the same. So you did not actually fix any problem.

The warning says that the allocated array may be too short. Why you get this warning with `malloc` but not with `_malloca` I don't know. But if the compiler was right initially then the problem is still there.

Be very careful with `_malloca`! The memory allocated by it may be released as soon as the function leaves its scope. And it must be released by a call to `_freea`. You may want to carefully read the reference documentation of this function and make sure you really understand the details.

And you may of course want to check whether the warning you got from the compiler initially is something real or whether the compiler is wrong.

Comment: You are right _malloca initially allocates memory in the stack but if it exceeds a certain memory it allocates it in the heap.